# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, exception, httpwebrequest

I am seeing following exception.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Web.Util.StringUtil.memcpyimpl(Byte* src, Byte* dest, Int32 len)
>      at System.Web.Util.StringUtil.UnsafeStringCopy(String src, Int32 srcIndex, Char[] dest, Int32 destIndex, Int32 len)
>      at System.Web.HttpWriter.Write(String s)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.Write(String s)

I already have following checks on the context to which I am responding.

```
return !(context == null || context.Response == null ||
    context.Response.OutputStream == null ||
    !context.Response.OutputStream.CanWrite);
```

Can anyone hint on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's where the error is? Looks like the exception started from the Write method of HttpResponse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error while working with asynchronous handlers and modules. My problem was that I would use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` from within the `HttpHandler's EndProcessRequest` method and within the work item callback I would try to use the `HttpContext`. The trouble is once `EndProcessRequest` returns back to the caller (but the work item callback has not yet been invoked), the `HttpContext` object instance is no longer "mine" and ASP.NET has assumed control and is tearing it down. See http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother with all of those checks?  Why not just write out to the output stream and be done with it?

Also, where in the ASP.NET processing pipeline is this call being made?

Comment: // grab a local copy of the text writer
   TextWriter writer = context.Response.Output;   

   // write out the message map
   writer.Write("output data...");

Comment: @unknown (google): I mean, where in the processing pipeline.  Is this an HTTP handler?  An application event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is elsewhere, but I'd suggest writing this expression a little more directly without the negatives:

```
return context != null && context.Response != null &&
    context.Response.OutputStream != null &&
    context.Response.OutputStream.CanWrite;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening if you are trying to actually write a null object to the buffer IE:

```
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(null, 0, 0);
```

Also You could represent it as...

```
return (context != null && context.Response != null &&
    context.Response.OutputStream != null &&
    context.Response.OutputStream.CanWrite);
```